# How to use previously downloaded ica file for connecting again in citrix?

Tags: citrix

So I downloaded ica file from my firm's site. That site seems down now and hence I cannot login to the system. This raises the question, can I use previously downloaded ica file, make changes to it and then use it to login again.

It seems like that file is only 80 lines long(can be easily opened by vim) and seems like simple characters. If someone knows that if some hash is being computed with your password and token or if they are directly being used somewhere and used, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ICA files use a one-time token (known as a secure ticket) to authenticate to your session. Once you've used this, you can't use it a second time. This is a security feature to stop people sending each other ICA files. If you site is down, just contact your service desk?

Comment: Thanks. This was useful :)